# Mac OS partition type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF after I tried to remove Linux partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, startup

I have Mac OS (catalina) with Linux Ubuntu and after I tried to remove the Linux partition my Mac can’t boot anymore ( I actually have no option to boot).

```
gpt -r show disk0 
diskutil list 
dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | vis -c
```

[image]

[image]

I read about this problem a lot but I just want to be sure that no data will be damaged while solving this issue because I don’t have any backup

What I’m going to do is

```
diskutil umountDisk disk0
gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 461916744 -t apfs  /dev/disk0
diskutil verifyDisk disk0
diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
```

Please tell me if I forget anything or I miss understood some commands, I’ll really appreciate that

Comment: No, the third command should be: `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 585490200 -t apfs  /dev/disk0`! The option *-s* (size) argument should have the same value as the FFFF...-type partition which will be "replaced"!

Comment: I think it didn’t work it shows me ( usage: gpt [-b lba] [-i index] [-s lba] [-t uuid] device ...)

Comment: Compared to your 3rd command only the -s argument's value differs but the basic composition of the command is correct! If your base macOS volume sys version is too old it may not handle your -t argument (apfs) correctly. Then you have to use: `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 585490200 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0`.  **Don't** use `diskutil verifyDisk|diskutil verifyVolume ...` afterwards because it can't check/verify APFS volumes/disks then!

Comment: Okay the command gpt add worked now I don’t need to use  ( diskutil verifyDisk|diskutil verifyVolume ) I just need to reboot! right ?

Comment: Booted to a Catalina recovery volume the `diskutil verifyDisk|diskutil verifyVolume ...` is recommended. But your recovery volume is too old and won't contain the necessary APFS drivers/info/utils to verify/fix anything APFS related. So simply try to boot to disk0 and verify the disk booted to Catalina. You won't be able to fix this "live" system though!

Comment: Well after the Mac rebooted successfully I’ve just noticed that the size of the Linux partition is missing do I need to resize the disk in terminal in the recovery mode ?

Comment: No, you can simply resize the APFS container from within the Catalina system: `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0`